# how to join two tables where the condition 'Where' is related to a third table that is associated with the first table

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework

I have the below relationship between tables Morden, Mproductos, and Mdistributor. I am able to select all Morden where Mdistributors.Name = 'DVerdersoto' as shown in the code below. How do I use linq to entity to show the Mordern and the Mproductos related to it. I know that you need to join the table MOrden and Mproductos where Mdistributor.Name = "DVerdesoto" but how do you do that. It can be lambda notation or any other notation it does not matter.

I also look this link but my case is different:

[Join multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978275/linq-to-entities-multiple-join)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

[image]

Code looking so far

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var context = new EDMmanytomanyContainer())
        {                
          var result = context.MOrdens.Where(s => s.Mdistributors.Any(c=> c.Nombre=="DVerdesoto"));                                                                     
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a navigation property `Mproductos` on your `MOrden` object, I think you're just missing one piece:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var context = new EDMmanytomanyContainer())
        {                
          var result = context.MOrdens
                              .Where(s => s.Mdistributors.Any(c=> c.Nombre=="DVerdesoto"))
                              .SelectMany(mo => mo.Mproductos);                                                                     
        }
    }
```

Assuming you are identifying duplicates by their Id value, you can change your LINQ to the following:

```
          var result = context.MOrdens
                              .Where(s => s.Mdistributors.Any(c=> c.Nombre=="DVerdesoto"))
                              .SelectMany(mo => mo.Mproductos)
                              .GroupBy(mp => mp.Id)
                              .Select(group => group.First());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What if would want to get the same query but avoiding duplicates of Mproductos ?

Comment: maybe you can help me with the last thing. I link the result to a DataSource of a datagrid view.But it does not show you the columns for Mordens( ID and Fecha) that is what i was loking for. Can you help me with this please ?. Basically I want to join table Mproductos and MMOrdens where Mdistributors.Nombre == "DVerdesoto"